# Audio from URL not playing with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I want to reproduce an audio file hosted in my server when pressing a button. When I press it nothing happens, this is my code:

```
@IBAction func Reproducir(sender: AnyObject) {

    let urlString = "http://...com/marchas/\(pasarid).mp3"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)

    avPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MPMoviePlayer to play streaming audio.

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerclass  will work for you.

AVPlayer does not support streaming. It only plays file locally

Comment: How can I use it for audio? I'm pretty new with Swift

Comment: Just google it. You can easily find the solutio .